# Error when I load RDF triples on Virtuoso TripleStore

Tags: java, rdf, jena, virtuoso, triplestore

I have a question.

I'm following the sample8 on http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtJenaProvider.

In particular, I have this code:

```
package ExampleVirtuoso;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode;
import virtuoso.jena.driver.*;

public class ExampleVirtuoso {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*          STEP 1          */
        VirtGraph set = new VirtGraph("jdbc:virtuoso://localhost:1111", "dba", "dba");

        /*          STEP 2          */
        System.out.println("\nexecute: CLEAR GRAPH <http://test1>");
        String str = "CLEAR GRAPH <http://test1>";
        VirtuosoUpdateRequest vur = VirtuosoUpdateFactory.create(str, set);
        vur.exec();

        System.out.println("\nexecute: INSERT INTO GRAPH <http://test1> { <aa> <bb> 'cc' . <aa1> <bb1> 123. }");
        str = "INSERT INTO GRAPH <http://test1> { <aa> <bb> 'cc' . <aa1> <bb1> 123. }";
        vur = VirtuosoUpdateFactory.create(str, set);
        vur.exec();

        /*          STEP 3          */
        /*      Select all data in virtuoso */
        System.out.println("\nexecute: SELECT * FROM <http://test1> WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }");
        Query sparql = QueryFactory.create("SELECT * FROM <http://test1> WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }");

        /*          STEP 4          */
        VirtuosoQueryExecution vqe = VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory.create(sparql, set);

        ResultSet results = vqe.execSelect();
        while (results.hasNext()) {
            QuerySolution rs = results.nextSolution();
            RDFNode s = rs.get("s");
            RDFNode p = rs.get("p");
            RDFNode o = rs.get("o");
            System.out.println(" { " + s + " " + p + " " + o + " . }");
        }

        System.out.println("\nexecute: DELETE FROM GRAPH <http://test1> { <aa> <bb> 'cc' }");
        str = "DELETE FROM GRAPH <http://test1> { <aa> <bb> 'cc' }";
        vur = VirtuosoUpdateFactory.create(str, set);
        vur.exec();

        System.out.println("\nexecute: SELECT * FROM <http://test1> WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }");
        vqe = VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory.create(sparql, set);
        results = vqe.execSelect();
        while (results.hasNext()) {
            QuerySolution rs = results.nextSolution();
            RDFNode s = rs.get("s");
            RDFNode p = rs.get("p");
            RDFNode o = rs.get("o");
            System.out.println(" { " + s + " " + p + " " + o + " . }");
        }

    }
}
```

I have added to my build path this libraries:

```
virtjdbc3.jar
virt_jena.jar
Jena libs
```

but when I compile this code, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.JenaException: virtuoso.jdbc3.VirtuosoException: Connection failed: Connection refused: connect
    at virtuoso.jena.driver.VirtGraph.<init>(VirtGraph.java:206)
    at virtuoso.jena.driver.VirtGraph.<init>(VirtGraph.java:93)
    at ExampleVirtuoso.ExampleVirtuoso.main(ExampleVirtuoso.java:10)
Caused by: virtuoso.jdbc3.VirtuosoException: Connection failed: Connection refused: connect
    at virtuoso.jdbc3.VirtuosoConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at virtuoso.jdbc3.VirtuosoConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at virtuoso.jdbc3.VirtuosoConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at virtuoso.jdbc3.Driver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at virtuoso.jena.driver.VirtGraph.<init>(VirtGraph.java:191)
    ... 2 more
```

I have tried to change

> virt_jena.jar

with

> virt_jena2.jar

, but I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: virtuoso/jdbc4/VirtuosoConnectionPoolDataSource
    at virtuoso.jena.driver.VirtGraph.<init>(VirtGraph.java:70)
    at virtuoso.jena.driver.VirtGraph.<init>(VirtGraph.java:92)
    at ExampleVirtuoso.ExampleVirtuoso.main(ExampleVirtuoso.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: virtuoso.jdbc4.VirtuosoConnectionPoolDataSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

I premise to be ignorant about the functionally of Virtuoso and I may omitted some initial step.
I have downloaded the libraries on http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSDownload#Jena%20Provider

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This first exception tells you that you tried to connect with a system which doesn't host the needed services, so either your connection string is wrong or you need to start whichever service you need or check your firewall settings and such. "Connection refused" is pretty obvious some kind of configuration problem with the service you want to connect to.

Comment: I think that I don't start the Virtuoso Server. How I can do it?

Comment: No idea, read the manual. ;-) http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSBuild

Comment: To start the Virtuoso Server:
1) Open a console 
2) Cd in the path where the virtuoso is installed and go to the folder 'database'
3) Delete the virtuoso.lck file
4) Execute virtuoso-t -f &